# How to add condition when element presented only?

Tags: robotframework

My app behave like this:

Add items -> user clicks Add button -> app return to main page
IF there are too many items, after user clicks Add button -> new dialog prompt 'waiting...', then user click OK button -> user click send button again
it is a loop if the new dialog prompt after send button is clicked. (from manual testing, this dialog could appear 2-3 times only).

I have written test case after click add ->
if there is dialog appear then click ok -> click add -> back to mainpage.
it is working fine when the new dialog appear.
I noticed if the new dialog does not appear, ROBOT still proceed to the ${VERIFIED} lines....this causing the script pausing for quite sometimes. no error but how do I get rid of it?

However the application may prompt the dialog many times when server loading is slow.

I want robot press this ok whenever dialog appear again then click add.
How do I achieve it?

```
    Add Item
        Click Add
        ${VERIFIED}     Run Keyword And Return Status    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@text='Please wait']     3s
        Run Keyword If    ${VERIFIED}   Wait Until Page Contains And Click    ${ANDROID-WIDGET-BUTTON}\[@text='OK']
        Run Keyword If    ${VERIFIED}   Click Add
        Wait Until Page Contains Navigation Bar Title    MainPage
```

Comment: What is the maximum timeout for the server to load? If that is defined you can repeat some actions in that time frame with a loop or the `Repeat Keyword`, `Wait Until Keyword Succeds` keyword.

Comment: i think Wait Until Keyword Succeeds much suitable, i am not sure, i though it is like keep pressing the ok button, but i need press ok, press add, press ok if there is? it is not about server timeout. if user click add button too quick then the dialog prompt. once user click ok to exit dialog then click add button again before server complete process, the dialog will be prompted again.

Comment: is for loop suitable? i need to exit it once item added sucessfully. i am not sure how to modify it to have for loop.

Comment: modified description and script to have better understanding

Comment: If you know where this OK button needs to be handled, add **Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Click OK**

Comment: What is the purpose of ignore error? Ignore if dialog appear or not? If appear then? If not appear then?